# Can't boot Freya 0.3.1 from USB on Macbook Pro Early 2011

Tags: boot, usb-drive, macbook

I got my Mac book Pro back from service and of course I tried booting Elementary OS from USB that was made with Unetbootin and boots on Lenovo x220.

First boot resulted in *ACPI PCC probe failed*. Googled it and found solution to hit *e* key in grub menu and add *nomodeset* in kernel parameters. Tried again and this time I get busybox terminal after this message:

> (initramfs) unable to find a medium containing a live file system

[image: screenshot of error msg]

Any ideas what might be the cause of this?

Edit: Elementary OS installed on Virtual Box in El Capitan installed and booted without a hick.

Comment: Have you changed boot order? If done, change USB socket and try again, and let me know.

Comment: The USB might be corrupt. Copy elementary OS to the USB again (I recommend Rufus if you have a Windows PC or Unetbootin for Ubuntu ) and try

Comment: What did they do at service ? Maybe a hardware component was changed

Comment: Whole motherboard was changed because this model has a recognised GPU issue.

Answer (score 1):

The *possible* fixes:

1. Check Boot order
2. Disable ACPI from BIOS
3. Change the port for the USB_stick connection
4. When elemenary is booting from live usb  hit Del/F10  then choose <kbd>F6</kbd> (Other Options).

   then check `acpi=off` & `nodmraid`.

Comment: There's no BIOS in Macbook, it's an EFI only laptop. I tried both USB ports with the same result. I will comment on the recommended boot options after more testing.

Answer (score 0):

If your laptop has a dvd drive, I recommend you boot from a live dvd. Insert the dvd and hold alt/option key until the dvd drive shows.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

https://sevenbits.github.io/Mac-Linux-USB-Loader/

It worked on my Macbook Pro 2010